# Is using PDO::prepare() with PDOStatement::execute() the correct option for single queries?

Tags: php, pdo

The PHP manual states the following:

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that
>   will be issued multiple times with different parameter values
>   optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver
>   to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and
>   meta information, and helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by
>   eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.

[PHP PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

For a single, once a page query - say:

```
$query = "SELECT id, content FROM pages WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
```

Is using prepare and execute like:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare( $query );
$statement->execute( array( ":id" => 5 ) );
```

The best way to go? I get a feeling from the manual that I should only be using prepare() for queries that will be bound multiple times. If this is the case, what are the other options? (Manually calling quote, and then PDO::query() possibly?)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php check the examples too. It explains there what you re asking.

Comment: Both example #1 and example #2 in the manual show cases of multiple queries i.e. they execute multiple times (in those examples it's red fruit and yellow fruit). I am talking about a single query. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say if there are any performance implications when using prepared statements for a single query only.

Every query is parsed, analyzed and optimized. That also applies to `PDO:query()` (and `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*`, …). Prepared Statements - simply put - separate parsing, analyzing, optimizing and query-planning from executing the query. My (possibly naiive) assumption is that the only overhead prepared statmenets pose for a single query is the caching of the prepared results.

Using one API for executing queries should outweigh slight performance penalties, though. If you were to use `PDO::query()` instead of `PDO::prepare()` for single queries, you'd miss out on on the parameter binding and automatic escaping `prepare()` offers out of the box. This - potentially - opens a new can of worms, should you forget to `PDO::quote()` your data.

I only use `PDO::query()` for things that cannot be prepared in a reasonable fashion (e.g. "static" queries like `SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY bla DESC LIMIT 1` and queries heavily using `IN()` et all).